# Similar matrix that is the same by permutation transformation of its own.

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism, adjacency-matrix, permutation-matrices

I'm attacking to solve the graph isomorphism problem using the adjacent matrices. If two adjacent matrices of the input graphs $G_a$ and $G_b$ connect with a permutation matrix, then $G_a$ and $G_b$ are isomorphic.

Following statement is in the proof I’m working on. At first, I thought that it is trivial. However, I was worried that the following assumptions were correct.

Suppose the matrix $B$ consists $b_{i, j} = 1$ for $i \neq j$ and $b_{i, i} = 0$ (Then, $B$ is the adjacent matrix of the complete graph). When $P^t B P = B$, $P$ should be a permutation matrix.

I thought that since $P$ is ​​symmetric, $P$ is orthogonal. $P$ is ​​neither rotation nor inversion. Because the elements of $B$ are not changed. However, I wondered it is really correct.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Were did you get stuck when trying to verify this statement?

Comment: This statement is in the proof I’m working on. At first, I thought that it is trivial. Since $B$ is  ​​symmetric, $P$ is orthogonal. $P$ is ​​neither rotation nor inversion. Because the elements of $B$ is not changed.

However, I wondered it really correct. Because I’m prone to mistake…

Comment: When providing clarification that is essential, please click on the tiny `edit` and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) and improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added my short proof after my statement.